# Select 1 Row Per Day For Each Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have a table with over 60 million rows. Snapshots taken at multiple times a day for all databases across all instances. I am trying to reduce the rows in my select by only returning 1 snapshot per database/instance per day.

My current query using (SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT  instance_name ,
        DU.database_name ,
        DU.collection_time ,
        DU.dbsize ,
        DU.logsize ,
        DU.reservedpages ,
        DU.usedpages
FROM    [core].[snapshots_internal] AS [SI]
LEFT JOIN [core].[source_info_internal] AS [SII] ON [SI].[source_id] = [SII].[source_id]
INNER JOIN [core].[snapshot_timetable_internal] AS [STI] ON [SI].[snapshot_time_id] = [STI].[snapshot_time_id]
LEFT JOIN [snapshots].[disk_usage] AS [DU] ON [SI].[snapshot_id] = [DU].[snapshot_id]
WHERE   instance_name LIKE '%\DEV'
        AND DU.[database_name] NOT LIKE 'tempdb'
        AND DU.[database_name] NOT LIKE 'master'
        AND DU.[database_name] NOT LIKE 'model'
        AND DU.[database_name] NOT LIKE 'msdb'
GROUP BY SII.instance_name
ORDER BY SII.instance_name ,
         DU.database_name ,
         DU.collection_time;
```

Returns the following:

```
2015-08-09 23:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-10 05:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-10 11:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-10 17:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-10 23:30:04.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 05:30:03.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 11:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 12:30:28.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 17:30:03.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 23:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-12 05:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-12 11:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
```

I would like to obtain:

```
2015-08-09 23:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-10 23:30:04.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-11 23:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
2015-08-12 11:30:02.0000000 +00:00  665600  64960   484170
```

After some research on other stack posts I was able to find similar questions but the responses still had me returning multiple rows per day. So any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

EX of something i tried:

```
select collection_time, du.snapshot_id, du.database_name 
from   snapshots.disk_usage du 
where du.collection_time in 
(
   select max(du.collection_time) 
   from snapshots.disk_usage du 
   group by collection_time
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often you can use row_number() to select only certain rows of the data. so maybe something like this would work:

```
select * from (
  SELECT  
    instance_name ,
    DU.database_name ,
    DU.collection_time ,
    DU.dbsize ,
    DU.logsize ,
    DU.reservedpages ,
    DU.usedpages,
    row_number() over (
      partition by instance_name, DU.database_name, convert(date, DU.collection_time)
      order by DU.collection_time desc) as RN
    ...
) X
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY instance_name ,
         database_name ,
         collection_time;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Do you know of another way to get the results without having to use "partition by"? I have a very big table and apparently from what I have read, partition by isnt the most efficient to use?

Comment: query takes 10 minutes to run for me unfortunately. I was able to get it down from 18 minutes, but at the cost of splitting my data set into 2 different environments.

Comment: Partition is required when using OVER for this sort of query. Generally speaking it's often comparable to a group by but it depends on the indexing of your table. Consider revamping or adding indexing to support this summary query.